# How to find the most common strings between rows

Tags: query, sql-server-2017

In SQL 2017, I have a 'food' table as follows:

```
ID    item    Ingredients
----  -----   -----------
1     item1   flour,sugar,cocoa,butter
2     item2   flour,sugar,butter,water
3     item3   sugar,cocoa,water
4     item4   sugar,cocoa,butter
5     item5   flour,water
```

Although the "Ingredients" are a CSV in a single field, I have no problem moving them to a related table:

```
ID    Ingredient
---   ----------
 1    flour
 1    sugar
 1    cocoa
 1    butter
 2    flour
```

etc
or just select them with a `CROSS APPLY string_split`

```
select ID, item, ingredient
from food
CROSS APPLY string_split(food.ingredients,',') as ing
```

Now here is what I am trying to attempt:

For any given row ex:`(where id = 1)` I want to return the top n rows (other than `id = 1`) that have the most common ingredients with `id = 1`.

So the top 2 with the most common ingredients with `id = 1` should be:

```
ID    item    Ingredients
----  -----   -----------
2     item2   flour,sugar,butter,water    ( 3 in common)
3     item3   sugar,cocoa,water           ( 2 in common)
4     item4   sugar,cocoa,butter          ( 3 in common)
5     item5   flour,water                 ( 1 in common)
```

The result should return rows with `id = 2` and `id = 4` as both have 3 ingredients in common with row `id = 1`

This is my first question on StackExchange, and I hope it is clear.
I can write this as a C# or Python batch program to create a table of 'closest ingredients', but I'm hoping I can do this in SQL.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please store the ingredients in a table not a list.  So let's call that `ItemIngredient` with two columns `ItemId` and `Ingredient` and leave it at that.  The primary key will be `(ItemId, Ingredient)`.  Because searches by `Ingredient` will probably happen a lot, let's put a non-unique index on `Ingredient` (which is necessary for below to work the most efficiently).

```
SELECT
  ItemId
 ,MatchItemId
 ,IngredientMatchCount
 ,MatchRank
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      Base.ItemId
     ,Match.ItemId AS MatchItemId
     ,COUNT(*) AS IngredientMatchCount
     ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Base.ItemId ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, Match.ItemId) AS MatchRank
    FROM
      ItemIngredient Base
    INNER JOIN
      ItemIngredient Match
        ON Match.Ingredient = Base.Ingredient 
             AND Match.ItemId <> Base.ItemId
    -- Put your WHERE clause here if you want to only fine matches for certain Ids
    GROUP BY
      Base.ItemId
     ,Match.ItemId
  ) matched
WHERE
  MatchRank <= 1 --Or whatever
ORDER BY
  ItemId
```

You can experiment with `RANK` vs `DENSE_RANK` at some point to see what provides the best results for you.  If you need details about the `Item` you can join back in the outer query.